# List movies as text in iPad 2 native video application, no preview graphic

Tags: ipad

I would like to see more of my video titles on the same screen using iPad 2's native "Videos" app.  But the video summary page wastes space by showing a rectangle preview of each video.  Is there a way to list iPad 2 movies in a table containing just title and other textual data about the movie?

The iPhone displays videos as a table of titles and other info, without any graphic of a video preview.  Can I get the table of titles on the iPad?

Comment: Excellent question, I'm looking forward to a simple answer as I have the same need.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Hopefully somebody changes this in the next revision.

Comment: It definitely isn't, at least not without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved this problem using an application called "File Browser."  Instead of sending files to the Video section of iTunes, use the App File Sync feature of iTunes to send the files to File Browser.  Note that other file utility apps should work as well too, not just the one I use (called File Browser).

After moving the files to the file app, you can browse the files from the app.  File Browser will start video files using the iPad's native Video viewing program.  So it accomplishes the goal stated in my quesion.

Since I started doing this I now use a Windows program called [Disk Aid](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid) which emulates iTunes to the iPad and allows you to have total control over the iPad's file structure for copying files to and from the device.  I still use File Browser on the iPad to start the video files from the iPad.  I use Disk Aid to move files to the iPad instead of iTunes, and I start video files on the iPad using File Browser, which then allows me to run the videos in the native iPad video program.